# Boolean fields on mongoose not setting value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman, mongoose-schema

I am writing small REST API  using mongoose, mongoDb and expressjs  for my front-end application. I have problem saving Boolean array Object. Other array Objects saved on database as expected, but the Boolean values get unexpected id's instead of values, except the first array value. Here is my code: 
the Model schema:

```
const companiesSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    benefitsOffers: [
        {
        balance : Boolean
        },
         {
        car: Boolean
        },
        {
        bonseModel: Boolean
        }, 
        {
        centerlaOffice: Boolean
        }, 
        {
        owenerShip: Boolean
        }, 
       ]
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('Companies', companiesSchema);
```

Test value sent  from Postman

```
    {

     "benefitsOffers": [
        {
            "balance": true

        },

        {
            "car": false

        },
        {
            "bonseModel": true

        },
        {
            "centerlaOffice": true

        },
        {
            "owenerShip": true

        },
]
```

}

Server response

```
 {
    "_id": "5ad93a2bd60c32622a8fce1d",
      "benefitsOffers": [
                {
                    "_id": "5ad93a2bd60c32622a8fce34",
                    "balance": true
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5ad93a2bd60c32622a8fce33"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5ad93a2bd60c32622a8fce32"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5ad93a2bd60c32622a8fce31"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5ad93a2bd60c32622a8fce30"
                },

    }
```

I have similar array structure for other data types and there is no problem.  what did i miss? , i referenced the official documentation and it does not have any specific thing about Boolean array object. I just need someone pinpoint my error

Comment: Mongoose cannot track array members with different property names like that. They are essentially "different schemas" and there is no such support for doing that ( in this way ) within array members. This does not really make sense as an "array" anyway. You either want something like `[{ "type": "balance", "value": true },{ "type": "car", "value": false }]` or `"benefitsOffers": { "balance": true, "car": false }`. So essentially you really should change the structure as your present one really does not make sense.

Comment: @Nel Lunn, actually Mongoose does track different array members, I used for other datatype, the only problem i have is for Boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution

**Create** `benefitsOffers` as a separate schema

```
const benefitsOffersSchema =  new Schema({
    balance : { type : Boolean, default: false },
    car : { type : Boolean, default: false },
    bonseModel : { type : Boolean, default: false },
    centerlaOffice : { type : Boolean, default: false },
    owenerShip : { type : Boolean, default: false }
});
```

**Attach** `benefitsOffersSchema` to `companiesSchema`

```
const companiesSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    benefitsOffers : [benefitsOffersSchema]
})
const Companies = mongoose.model("Companies",companiesSchema);
module.exports = Companies;
```

**Now** you can insert the boolean values

```
var benefitsOffers = {
    balance : true,
    car : true,
    bonseModel : false,
    centerlaOffice : false,
    owenerShip : false
};
var company = new Companies({ benefitsOffers : benefitsOffers});
company.save();
```

**Below** is the output of inserted document

[image]